# Making a list in console! Java! very simple just need quick assist

Tags: java

Okay So how would i make my printscreen statement look like this in the console:

> Welcome to the 55x2 Dice Game!
>
> Dice Game Menu:
>
> [1]: Play Now!
>
> [2]: How to Play
>
> [3]: Exit

And also quick question, what do i write to exit the application if it's selected to?

Comment: Have you tried, eg, `System.out.println("[1]: Play Now!");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`System.out.println("text")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.String%29) to print a new line with the text that you pass as an argument.

To exit the application use:

```
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Hmm.......okay, how would i space the lines? Just by hitting enter inbetween blocks of code? and thanks!

Comment: @iSully just call `println` multiple times, or embed a `\n` e.g. `"[1]: Play Now!\n[2] ..."` `\n` is the escape character for a line feed.

Comment: `println` will print whatever you pass to it. So if you want some line to have spaces, just pass it a string with spaces, i.e., "Some text". If you want multiple lines, call `println` multiple times; each will print a new line. You should really read some basic Java book before getting started.